# Not a valid ELF image

Tags: 12.04, boot, boot-failure, mac

After installing 12.04.01 LTS on a iMac G5, at the boot prompt, the message

> not a valid ELF image

prevents me from booting.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Grabbed from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1748661)

You may need to download the alternate iso and install it

once done please follow the steps

- Install PPC via CLI `cli-powerpc641`
- Use **ports.ubuntu.com** as mirror for repository
- Finish installer & reboot
- Login via command line and install ubuntu desktop using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xorg ubuntu-desktop`
- Reboot